# CSF/LFD: Firewall automatically disabling again and again

Tags: firewall, centos7, csf, lfd

I have setup a droplet on Digital Ocean, and installed CentOS Web Panel. After the initial configuration, I've enabled CSF/LFD firewall. But it is automatically disabling, again and again. I have enabled 3 time in last 24 hours.

I **want to know:** where can I find error log OR how do I trace why it's disabling and fix it?

**Update:** I found from logs that only `lfd` daemon is stopping with this error message in logs **Unable to fork: Cannot allocate memory**. I've upgraded droplet from **1 GB** to **2 GB** ram droplet, but it is still happening.

I am pretty sure, there is some bug or any other problem because it is suppose to work on **1 GB** server.

Please somebody help...

Comment: Please add more details: what are the outputs of `systemctl status csf lfd` and `journalctl -xe`? Also, make sure that `TESTING = "0"` in `/etc/csf/csf.conf`.